# VHDL: converting an std_logic_vector to an integer (works in simulation, not practice)

Tags: vhdl, fpga

The past two days I have been fighting this one problem. I want data_out to send "111" in this case, seeing how the entire memory is filled with '1'. I will show the code and then make the question more precise:

```
entity tile_library is
  Port (
    data_out : out std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
    data_in : in std_logic_vector(5 downto 0);
    clk : in std_logic);

end tile_library;

architecture Behavioral of tile_library is

type memory_type is array (0 to 63) of std_logic_vector(255 downto 0);
signal memory : memory_type := (others=> (others=>'1'));
signal something_to_convert : std_logic_vector(5 downto 0) := "000000";


begin
  process(clk) begin
  if rising_edge(clk) then
    if memory(to_integer(unsigned(data_in)))(5) = '1' then
      data_out <= "111";
    else
      data_out <= "000";
    end if;

  end if;
end process;


end Behavioral;
```

If I replace

```
    if memory(to_integer(unsigned(data_in)))(5) = '1' then
```

with

```
    if memory(to_integer(unsigned(something_to_convert)))(5) = '1' then
```

I get "111" as output on my nexys 3 card.

This leads me to believe data_in is not what it should be.

Therefore, I show you the code which yields data_in to the tile_library in my tests:

```
entity tile_memory is
  Port (
    data_out : out std_logic_vector(5 downto 0);
    clk : in std_logic);

end tile_memory;

architecture Behavioral of tile_memory is

begin
  process(clk)
  begin
   if rising_edge(clk) then
     data_out <= "000000";

   end if;
  end process;

end Behavioral;
```

To further confusion, I could add that according to *simulations*, I get the exact same in and out signals (which are also the correct ones, "111") with both `if memory(to_integer(unsigned(data_in)))(5) = '1' then` and `if memory(to_integer(unsigned(something_to_convert)))(5) = '1' then`. When I run it on my Nexys 3 card; however, they yield different results.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: This line : `signal memory : memory_type := (others=> (others=>'1'));` contains a pre-initialisation of memory, which may not be supported in synthesis. For diagnostic purposes, why not transmit `data_in` directly rather than worrying what it *might* be?

Comment: You didn't indicate what the output was if you don't replace. It's even worse that @BrianDrummond indicates.  Your memory type memory_type is initialized to all '1''s all 256 elements of the std_logic_vector that is the element type of all 64 positions.  It can be optimized away unless you have some way of writing different values to memory. It literally doesn't matter was data_in is, and that can likely be optimized away in synthesis too, it's always all '0's.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with

```
signal memory : memory_type := (others=> (others=>'1'));
```

In Xilinx software it works for me all the time.

I'd suggest using chipscope and place a keep/mark_debug attribute on the signals you want to view because as others point out it will be optimized out. But that doesn't mean you should be getting the wrong result.

data_out should be "000" (due to Xilinx synthesis assumption) for the first clock cycle then "111" for consecutive clock cycles.

If synthesis is stuffing it up my guess is that it doesn't like the ram operation as part of an if statement (I've personally never seen it before). Try taking it out of the if statement (as shown below). This should not be required but XST can be rather sensitive when it comes to recognizing memory/multipliers etc.

You can also look look at a post synthesis schematic/simulation but I suggest chipscope first.

```
entity tile_library is
  Port (
    data_out : out std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
    data_in : in std_logic_vector(5 downto 0);
    clk : in std_logic);

end tile_library;

architecture Behavioral of tile_library is

type memory_type is array (0 to 63) of std_logic_vector(255 downto 0);
signal memory : memory_type := (others=> (others=>'1'));
signal something_to_convert : std_logic_vector(5 downto 0) := "000000";
signal memory_read_data : std_logic_vector(255 downto 0);

begin
  memory_read_data <= memory(to_integer(unsigned(data_in)));
  process(clk) begin
  if rising_edge(clk) then
    if memory_read_data(5) = '1' then
      data_out <= "111";
    else
      data_out <= "000";
    end if;

  end if;
end process;


end Behavioral;
```